# Recognising a screen size change

Tags: screen-options

I trying to understand what is happening with the Wordpress theme that I am using. The menu is found on the right hand side of the page and when the window size is made smaller it changes to a single drop down from the middle (for smaller devices). On inspection I can see that there are various classes that seem to handle the appearance:

```
.menu-toggle,
.main-small-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on {
display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navigation-main ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu-toggle {
background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-top: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    color: #1e1e1e;
etc etc 
}
```

When the screen size is reduced the main-small-navigation class is used and all is fine. When the screen is put back however the menu is not displayed correctly.

What I am trying to figure out is how any of this might be called when you change the size of the screen. I realise this might be a vague and possibly theme specific but any pointers as to what I should be looking for would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called responsive design and has nothing to do with Wordpress, it is an extension rule to media queries (*`@media`*) in CSS3. CSS is a browser/client side language which can determine window sizes and browser types, this is what is used to determine how a website should look at a specific window size or browser. This media queries, when specified in CSS, will be used to resize a specific item to the required set size accordingly

Some themes also incorporate javascript together with CSS to display HTML selectors differently on different window sizes and browser types.

I'm not going to go into more details as this really is not Wordpress specific, you should take your time to read up on responsive design and media queries

Answer (score 1):

The `@media` query is being used to change styles depending on window size.

Example which changes the height of the masthead when the min-width of the window is 800px

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
.masthead.shrink {
    height: 50px;    
}
}
```

so you can check your css style and look for any @media queries and modify accordingly.

[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)